# How is this translation of "the immutable system engenders rot"?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

My sentence is "the immutable system engenders rot." Diagramming the English sentence:

- immutable: adjective, modifying the subject
- system: noun, subject. in context, refers to the system in the same sense as political system/constitutional order, or economic system
- engenders: our verb, passive, third person, present
- rot: our object, noun (but apparently not a gerund in english?)

For Latin vocabulary, I picked:

- [inmutabilis](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/inmutabilis)
- [mos](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mos#Latin) (maybe not a great choice?)
- [gigno](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/gigno) (note - english engender's is from latin ingenerare, when would you use which one?)
- [putesco](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/putesco)

giving me:

inmutabilis mos putescendum gignitur

Which is kind of a mouthful. Did I do the grammar right, and do you have any feedback on word choice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the most Latin way of translating this phrase, even if it means taking a little liberty, is "what doesn't move rots".

> Putescit quod non movet.

You may want to add "et non movetur" (and is not moved).

> Putescit quod non movet et non movetur.

Comment: The intransitive use of *moveo* is very rare classically. *Moveo* is a good choice otherwise because it does occur as a synonym for *muto*.

Comment: @Cairnarvon Yep! I distinctly remember getting marks off in early poetry composition because I used *moveo* without an object. Even if it occurs rarely, it would be very unusual to see in a motto. I would only go with the transitive passive here.

Answer (score 3):

We can also attempt a somewhat more literal translation.

- For "system," as in a political system, I would suggest *constitutio*, which seems like a good fit (unless, in a Neo-Latin context, it could be confused with the idea of a written constitution). *Mos*, I would not have understood as "system."
- *Putescendum* is wrong because in the accusative, you would use the infinitive; however, this seems like a very unusual way to phrase it. And there is a much simpler word for *rot* anyway: *caries*.

Thus we might say: **Immutabilis gignit constitutio cariem.**